# Why is Blender not procedural?

Tags: objects, edit-mode, vertices, procedural, source-code

best example, changing the vertices after you add a circle, same with cylinder, sphere segments and so on.
I think it is in the most 3D software like Maya, C4D and Houdini of course.

Has it something to do with the implementation/coding?

Best, Joseph

Comment: This is a very general question for this site, it may not be considered appropriate here.. but fear not! It's a good question, that hasn't passed  the developers by .. [This](https://developer.blender.org/T67088) might be a good starting point  for your exploration of Everything Nodes.. central to the strategic plan for Blender.

Comment: Blender can actually be very procedural. I use blender sort of as a free cad program, it isn't designed for it but it works well enough that i have been doing it professionally for the last 3 years. When I started I used a vertex-based workflow, it was tough because it was slow and destructive, it wasn't easy to go back and make changes. However, the real procedural stuff comes when you use modifier stacks. Fo me they have been huge time savers. they are non-destructive as long as you don't hit apply, they allow for tons of reversible and changeable procedural modeling or generation.